# Loadrunner - New install and requirements

Tags: loadrunner, requirements

I am about to start a new project where there will be a need to use Loadrunner. I do not have indepth experience of using this software however we are in the process of acquiring this product from HP but need clarification on the below questions.

Need for Loadrunner
The application is a Windows application where thousands of users can be logged in at the same time performing different tasks (updating records, uploading documents, running searches and many more tasks)

Questions
1.How many Virtual Users are required for testing?
2.Which Protocol(s) are required?

3.is this a perpetual license or Term (options are 1 Month, 3 Month, 12 Month and Perpetual).

Any help would be much appreciated, apologies in advance if my question seems a bit vague. I am a new to this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whlie purchasing the HP Loadrunner License tools,as based on license you will get access to run vusers.

**1.How many Virtual Users are required for testing?**

When coming to Virtual Users decision you can take for 100 vusers because while preparing the scenario ,you have to mention vusers for real world scenarios.I have observed one thing in controller when i have ran for 10 vusers with 30 minutes of time for web applications/SOAP/REST api services ,controller Hits around 80000 transactions and Hits/Second is 110 hits,means controller starts hitting the script as based on provided test data.So as per above details you can select VUsers.

**What Protocol?**

In my professional work ,i,m using HTTP/Webservices protocols for WebServices Testing and Web Application testing as per my need,Coming to your Need has to select what type of Applications you are going to Perform Load testing,It depends on Applications which you are going to Test.

**3.is this a perpetual license or Term (options are 1 Month, 3 Month, 12 Month and Perpetual).**

If you purchased licenses for several different bundles (such as Web 2.0 and Oracle E-business) or several different license types (such as Permanent and VUD) which share common protocols and you want to run Vusers that belong to both bundles/types—the licenses will be consumed in the following order:

**License type:**

1.Temporary License 
 2.Permanent and 
 3.time-limited license VUD license

Please read License details here
http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/License/ui_License_Utility_New_License.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need training and a mentor

> I do not have indepth experience of using this software ... The
>   application is a Windows application where thousands of users can be
>   logged in at the same time performing different tasks (updating
>   records, uploading documents, running searches and many more tasks)...

Calculate the cost of an hour of downtime or hundreds of hours of lost productivity due to a slow app.  This will dwarf the cost of training and a mentor to guide you through this process.

> How many Virtual users?

I haven't a clue.  This is going to take an examination of your current system, logs, reports of active sessions, discussions with the business.  Concurrency != licensed users

> What Protocol?

Haven't a clue.  This is going to take an architectural examination of your client application, the next upstream architectural component it connects to and what programming interface is leveraged.  It could be anything from sockets to CORBA|DCOM. With almost every protocol requiring a different skill set in terms of architecture and programming skills.

> License?

You can buy it by the day. You can buy it by the month.  You can by it by the year or forever.  You can buy it in the cloud or buy it to install onsite.  You can buy it on demand.  And if the protocol you need has not been evaluated before purchase, then you are likely to have to purchase something again.

Right now you are in a time of high financial risk.  The first item is that you are likely going to be purchasing something insufficient to meet your technical and business needs.  On the second front there is a particular set of skills you need to be successful as a performance tester.  You need them.  You do not have them.  The path is through training and mentoring.  The path you are on is not one of success.